# Trying to plot a graph using a list of column names using seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn

I'm trying to print a grid of seaborn plots by using a list of column names. It is plotting everything on the last plot.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize=(10,10), sharex=True)

for aa in listA:
    for j in range(2):
        for i in range(2):
            ax[i][j] = sns.lineplot(x='time', y=aa, data=new_df, color='r')
```

Output plot

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to flatten the ax and iterate through them. You can call plt from matplotlib directly:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib. pyplot as plt

dates = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', periods=10, freq='1D')
listA = [np.random.normal(0,1,10) for i in range(4)] 
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'time':dates })

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize=(10,10), sharex=True)
ax = ax.flatten()
for i,aa in enumerate(listA):
    ax[i].plot(new_df['time'], aa, color='r')
    ax[i].set_xticklabels(new_df['time'], rotation = 45, ha="right",fontsize=7)
```

[image]

If you really wanna use seaborn, it goes like:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize=(10,10), sharex=True)
ax = ax.flatten()
for i,aa in enumerate(listA):
    sns.lineplot(x=new_df['time'], y=aa, color='r',ax=ax[i])
    ax[i].set_xticklabels(new_df['time'], rotation = 45, ha="right",fontsize=7)
```

Comment: Is there a way to edit the x_axis label format? I need 'YYYY-MM-DD', instead of 'YYYY-MM-DD MM:HH:SS'

Comment: df['time'].dt.strftime('%y-%m-%d'). please avoid asking questions outside of your original question

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the following line of code:

```
ax[i][j] = sns.lineplot(x='time', y=aa, data=new_df, color='r')
```

with the following:

```
ax[i,j] = sns.lineplot(x='time', y=aa, data=new_df, color='r')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize=(15,5))
a = 0
for j in range(2):
    for i in range(2):
        sns.lineplot(x='time', y=listA[a], data=new_df[new_df['transportation_type']=='walking'], ax=ax[i,j])
        a+=1
```

Comment: Answer with explanation are more acceptable + votable